# Uncountable and Unbounded set of measure 0?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In my Real Anaysis course, the instructor posed a question. He asked to either give an example or to explain why it is not possible.

He asked about an uncountable and unbounded set of measure 0.

My instinct is that is does not exist, but I am not sure why. I do know that the Cantor Set is uncountable and has measure zero, but is most definitely bounded.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

**HINT:** Take disjoint translations of the Cantor set by a countable set.

**A DIFFERENT HINT:** Take an unbounded set of measure zero and take an uncountable set of measure zero. What's their union?

Comment: Even easier, take the Cantor set union the integers.

Comment: @Ross: Hah, yeah. :-)

Comment: Great minds think alike.

Comment: (For those who are bereft of context (which is lost in the editing grace period), I posted the answer and seconds later I edited to add the second hint, in the meantime Ross posted the comment.)

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes sense to me!

Comment: @Nick: You're welcome.